# Find MIN value in MYSQL (Not MIN() and Sorting)

Tags: mysql, min, cartesian-product

I would like to find a way to get minimum value from this

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (
val INT(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT Numbers(val)  VALUES (5), (6), (1), (-3)....
```

Without using `MIN()`, but using cartesian product and set operations.

Comment: Novelty `-max(-val)`

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the nubers table to itself:

```
select
  distinct n1.*
from
  numbers n1 left join numbers n2 on n2.val<n1.val
where
  n2.val is null
```

(this query will return all rows where the join does not succeed, those where the number is the minimum)